# format.parse убирает нули при записи даты

Tags: java, simpledateformat

Код

```
String stringMin = rowx[i9];//получаем строковое представление даты
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date dMin;
dMin = format.parse(stringMin);
```

получается такой вывод: 171.2018 18:06:18 вместо 17.01.2018 18:06:18

я тестировал в декабре,ноябре отрабатывало нормально. Видимо 0 как то не прописывается. Кто0нибудь сталкивался с таким?

Comment: Должно работать правильно. Попробуйте другую локаль - может в ней дело.

Comment: а что у вас присваивается переменной stringMin , когда вылетает такая ошибка?